# Add properties to array objects - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

How can I add properties to objects in an array by looping through the array?

Example I have an array with objects;
`$scope.addresses` contains many addresses.

And lets say that each object has only have 4 properties;

```
$scope.addresses[0].address_line1
$scope.addresses[0].address_line2
$scope.addresses[0].address_line3
$scope.addresses[0].city
```

Now I want to add more properties to each of the objects in the array.

```
$scope.addresses[0].location
$scope.addresses[0].neighbourhood
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Perfect use case for `Array.prototype.map()`

Comment: What is source of the property values?

Comment: I just want to manually add a property and set it to `true` or `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map` to loop the collection:

```
$scope.addresses = $scope.addresses.map(function(address) {
      address.location = "X";   
      return address;
});
```

Comment: You're modifying the addresses, may as well use a `forEach` and drop the return...

Comment: Or more simply `addresses.map(address => Object.assign({location: 'X'}, address))`

Comment: After your change it still looks silly, you're returning a new array that contains the same references because you are modifying items in place so both arrays are affected. Still should be using a `forEach`, or you should be returning modified objects in the map function. Sorry, but I really dislike the misuse of Array#map "use map to loop over a collection" is really bad advice, "use map to create a new array with modified items" is much more true to map's semantics

Answer (score 3):

Just assign a new property

```
$scope.addresses[0].location = 'Roxbury'
```

`$scope.addresses[0].location` must already be an object since you are setting  properties on it.

To loop over addresses, use forEach or a standard for loop:

```
$scope.addresses.forEach(function(address, index) {
    address.location = locations[index];
});

for(var i=0; i < $scope.addresses.length; i++) {
  $scope.addresses[i].location = myLocations[i];
}
```

Or you could replace the entire addresses object using map

```
scope.addresses = addresses.map(address => Object.assign(
    {location: 'X'}, address));
```

Comment: Yes I can assign a property like you mentioned. But that will be for just one of the object. Imagine I have 100 addresses in `$scope.addresses` how will I do it? I can't do it manually by adding `[0], [1]` etc... So I would need to loop and add to all

Comment: @shady87 That's correct, you don't know how to loop over the addresses?

Comment: Not in `angular` I'm a `PHP` developer

Answer (score 0):

Simply using the . dot notion should do.

```
$scope.addresses[0].location = 'Iceland';
```

Just check for existence of $scope.addresses[0] before you do the assignment though otherwise you will get trying to access property of 'undefined' errors.

so something like

```
if($scope.addresses[0])
    $scope.addresses[0].location = 'Iceland';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` loop and then add required items inside it:

```
angular.forEach($scope.addresses, function(v, k) {
    v.location = "New location " + (k + 1);
    v.neighbourhood = "New neighbourhood " + (k + 1);
  });
```

Watch demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/t3a67fk4/).